# Why does the Git credential manager need to implement each service separately?

Tags: git, https, credentials, credential-manager

Background: We have a local Gitea server in the office. I just started using it with [Git Credential Manager Core](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) enabled. Surprisingly (to me), I have to retype my password every time I want to `fetch` or `push` (over `https`).

After reading a bit in the GCM Core documentation and finding [a pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/issues/145) asking for Gitea support, it seems to me that this is because Gitea support is simply not implemented.

Now, here's where my question arises: I would have thought that `https` works the same no matter which service one is connecting to. Why does it matter if I am trying to push to Gitea or Github or some other service if all the credential manager has to do is safely store my credentials for later?

---

After some testing I discovered that this happens even after

```sh
git config credential.helper cache
```

so it's not even an issue with GCM Core. Why doesn't Git just cache the info?

---

Oh, I'm using Git for Windows (on Windows 10), if that matters.

Comment: What if you set `credential.helper=manager`? (Windows - which is your OS?)

Comment: Same thing. I'm also on Windows. Since `manager` is deprecated, I started out with `manager-core`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "reference". Do you mean for the deprecation? Then yes, the note on that site as well as in the [GCM Core faq](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/master/docs/faq.md#q-does-this-mean-gcm-for-windows-net-framework-based-is-deprecated). However, the behavior is the same, so it doesn't really matter, I think.

Comment: Are you saying that this is not normal, you are also using a Gitea remote and do not experience this? (My Git is up to date.)

Comment: I do not use Gitea, but I do use the old credential "manager". To me this looks odd, but I don't feel like I can solve this issue...

Comment: Try using the `wincred` credential helper.  It's less intimate with the various services it uses, so it's more likely to just work.